# C: creating named pipe using mknod() not working

Tags: c, pipe, mknod

Language: C
OS: Ubuntu

I'm simply trying to create a FIFO named pipe using the command:

```
state = mknod("pipe.txt", S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);
```

the problem is i always get the state's value to be -1 (meaning it has failed) instead of 0.

perror returns 'pipe.txt: File exists'

i have no idea how should i debug such issue or what could be the reason, hope anyone code guide me what's wrong.

(note: the file pipe.txt exist on same path as source file.)

Comment: "mknod() returns zero on success, or -1 if an error occurred (in which
case, errno is set appropriately)." What is `errno`?  If you use `perror`, this is very easy to see from the beginning.

Comment: Use `perror("mknod: pipe.txt")` after detecting `mknod()` failure.

Comment: When a system call such as `mkfifo` returns `-1` it means there is an error. To get the error you need to look at `errno`. To print a usable string version of the error code in `errno` use either `strerror` to get a printable string, or use `perror` to print it directly. However, you should only check `errno` **iff** a function failed (i.e. returned `-1` or `NULL` or what it specifies as a failed return value).

Comment: Your'e right about perror, the error im getting: 'pipe.txt: File exists'. it might be i don't understand how things work but i thought the file is suppose to be exist, isn't that the whole idea?

Comment: Popokoko, no, if you follow the link in my answer (http://linux.die.net/man/2/mknod), you'll see that it's _not_ supposed to exist. `mknod` _creates_ an entry in the filesystem space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read: [int mknod(const char *path, mode_t mode, rdev_t dev_identifier);](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zvm/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zvm.v610.edclv/rtmkn.htm)
**General Description**:
Creates a new character special file or FIFO special file (named pipe), with the path name specified in the path argument.

If file already exists then it will fails with error: `File exists`

To avoid this error, remove([`unlink()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink)) the file, As I am doing in my below code(*read comment*):

```
int main() {
  char* file="pipe.txt";
  unlink(file);  // Add before mknod()
  int state = mknod(file, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);
  if(state < 0){
    perror("mknod() error");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just make sure it's _your_ file before you unlink it :-)

Comment: thank you @Grijesh Chauhan, your code example clarify it. i had some misunderstanding of how things work. Also, thank you @paxdiablo!

Comment: small update: i think i messed up things, after using the unlink command im unable to run my project again, something is stuck in the background: while building it says: Blocked: The user operating is waiting for background work :(

Comment: @Popokoko consider Paxdiablo's comment also.

Comment: Do u have any idea how can i stop that blocked issue in the background?

Comment: @Popokoko Sorry Popokoko :( No idea!!...it may depends on your project as well, If its only due to after adding `unlink()` then first read unlink's man page, I linked.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Could we possibly turn this into a mimimum working example by adding all necessary `#include` statements?

Answer (score 0):

You should examine `errno` to see what the error is but it's probably `EEXIST` since I believe that's what happens if the file already exists.

From the [Linux documentation for `mknod`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mknod):

> If pathname already exists, or is a symbolic link, this call fails with an EEXIST error.

However, if the file already exists and *is* the pipe you created in an earlier run, you can safely reopen it. All `mknod` (and its often preferred cousin, `mkfifo`) does is actually *create* the FIFO, you still have to open it at both ends to get the data transfer happening.

Comment: Erm, I think i now get it, i was pretty sure it should get an EXISTING file, though i understand it should get a filedescriptor, or something like that

Comment: @Popokoko, you don't get a file descriptor from `mknod`, you only get a 0 or -1. You have to _open_ the created fifo in order to use it.